# How to explain the calculation of the determinant of a $4\times4$ matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

In my linear algebra lecture notes, I am studying an example which concerns the calculation of the determinant of a $4 \times 4$ matrix, by first reducing the matrix to upper triangular form.  (See page 40 of the PDF document at [this link](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masbal/LinAlg1011/lectures.pdf).

I do not yet understand the 'clever' observation which is referred to in the last sentence of the example.
Why is it true that the determinant of the original matrix is equal to the determinant of this smaller $2 \times 2$ matrix?

Comment: You could have taken some effort to describe the cleverness in words: rather than use row operations to reduce a $4\times4$ matrices all the way to triangular form, the "clever" thing is to stop when the matrix is _almost_ upper unit triangular, except for a $2\times2$ block at the bottom left, and the whole determinant is taken to be the determinant of that $2\times2$ block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because at the last but one step, the matrix is block-triangular so its determinant is the product of the determinants of the diagonal blocks:
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&2&1&1\\
0&1&1&2\\
0&0&4&5\\
0&0&3&1\end{vmatrix}
=\begin{vmatrix}1&2\\
0&1\end{vmatrix}
\cdot\begin{vmatrix}
4&5\\
3&1\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
4&5\\
3&1\end{vmatrix}$$

Answer (score 2):

See the step before the final step. Expand ( calculate ) the determinant along the first column. You'll see that only one 3*3 determinant survives. Again expand along first column . You'll see that only one 2*2 determinant survives.

Comment: I have seen an example in the past where the method you've just described (of calculating 'surviving' smaller matrices) is used to calculate the determinant of an initial larger matrix.  Could you please explain why this works?

Comment: @CKKOY See [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) of a determinant

Comment: @CKKOY Do you know about minors and cofactors? Your notes describe expanding a determinant along the first row but in fact it can be expanded along any row or column .  Read this to understand - http://www.purplemath.com/modules/minors.htm . ( There are three pages , but its worth it).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the approach you take to define determinants, you'll look for different explanations.

In case you use the Leibniz formula to define the determinant of a square matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1,\dots,n}$ as
$$
\det A = \sum_{\sigma\in S_n} \operatorname{sgn} \sigma \prod_{i=1}^n a_{\sigma(i),i},
$$
you can look at the possible $\sigma\in S_n$ that yield a non-zero summand. Since $a_{k,1}=0$ for $k\neq 1$, the permutation $\sigma$ needs to map $1$ to $1$ to produce a non-zero summand. In the next column, we have $a_{k,2}=0$ for $k\notin \{1,2\}$, so $\sigma$ has to map $2$ to either $1$ or $2$, but since already $\sigma(1)=1$ we conclude $\sigma(2)=2$. Hence, we can drop all other summands and only consider permutations of $\{3,4\}$:
$$
\det A = \sum_{\rho\in\operatorname{Sym}\{3,4\}} \operatorname{sgn}\rho \underbrace{a_{11} a_{22}}_1 \prod_{i=3}^4 a_{\rho(i),i} = \det \pmatrix{a_{33} & a_{34} \\ a_{43} & a_{44}}.
$$

If you already know more elaborate techniques like column expansion or determinants of block triangular matrices, you can of course apply those, as suggested by Bernard and A Googler.